# Raster to point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, point

I have a raster (5km pixel side) and I want to create a shapefile of points, one point per pixel (like a centroid), each point carring the correspondent pixel value. I run "RasterToPoint"tool in ArcGIS and it generate millions of points (cannot understand why). Does someone have aclue on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that the raster was the output of the "zonal statistics tool", where I used a 5x5km vector grid as reference. I thought the raster was automatically resampled at 5x5km pixel size, but it was not. Basically it was 30x30m pixel size and this is why I got such a huge amount of points.